# Delete tag "ratchet"

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a new tag of "ratchet" which was on one question only:
[Trigger shifters partly malfunctioning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50391)

Editing the tags on that question to remove the tag has not deleted it from SE.

I figured that "shifter" tag was good enough and covered the point of the question, whereas "ratchet" didn't add anything.

Suggest to delete the tag.

Comment: We need to adjust the settings so that it doesn’t take a moderator to edit tags.